# AX AOT query apply range modifiedDateTime on multiple tables

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, aot

I have the following case:

I've constructed a query joining multiple tables which have modifiedDateTime column. I need to apply a range filtering records which were last modified in either Table A or Table B, the joined tables (based on the modifiedDateTime value).

If I add the range to both data sources (for Table A and Table B), I retrieve records which were modified in BOTH tables, instead either of them.

The join type between the tables is OuterJoin.

How do I address this in the AOT query?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems to me, You have to create a Union query. The first part of the union query will be the range for the tableA and the second part the tableB.